# Proper way to determine if a user has already voted on a Thread/Post using the Disqus API?

Tags: php, api, disqus

The Disqus API docs at https://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/vote/ and https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/vote/ show some examples on registering votes for Posts and Threads, respectively.

These are the only documented API calls related to voting, and from the docs the calls are to be used to:

> Register a vote on a post.

and

> Register a vote on a thread.

So what API call should be used to determine if a user has already voted, and what their vote was? Is it up to the application developer utilizing the API to keep track of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you authenticate your API requests with an access token, any requests that include a `post` or `thread` will have a property called `userScore`.

On posts, this can be `-1`, `0` or `1`, which follows the same voting pattern in the `posts/vote` API.

A thread won't have downvotes of course, so it'll be limited to `0` or `1`

Comment: So just to clarify, `userScore` should be the vote the authenticated user previously registered for that thread/post?
And from that it appears the imposed pattern is to dynamically update the UI after the `xxxx/votes` call and then on subsequent loads use the `post` or `thread` object to get the userScore to see if it's already been voted on by the authenticated user.
Since the userScore on unvoted threads appears to be `0`, I assume there's no way to track whether the user has truly 'not voted' - only whether or not their current registered vote is not a `-1` (downvote) or `1` (upvote).

Comment: Also, since threads can't have downvotes, shouldn't https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/vote/ list *vote* **Choices: 0, 1** instead of *vote* **Choices: -1, 0, 1** - or is vote registration always relative?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if it's `0` you can be sure the user hasn't voted. The only reason you would call `posts/vote` or `threads/vote` with the value of `0` is if the user is trying to undo their vote if they accidentally clicked it.

Comment: Also, you _can_ downvote a thread, but the value is not used or represented anywhere in the product so there's no real point.

Comment: Thank you - the details you provided have been very helpful.